# Average if criteria range is plus or minus 5

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The formula below at the moment will average the first range only if the second range is equal to C10 AND the third range is equal to D11. This works perfectly as it should, but I would like to be able to change the first criteria so that it is within the range of C10-5 and C10+5 .

```
 =AVERAGEIFS('FR motor'!$O$4:$O$68788,'FR motor'!$N$4:$N$68788,$C10,'FR motor'!$E$4:$E$68788,D$11)
```

should work something like this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('FR motor'!$O$4:$O$68788,'FR motor'!$N$4:$N$68788,OR($C10,$C10+1,$C10+2,$C10+3,$C10+4,$C10+5),'FR motor'!$E$4:$E$68788,D$11)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed it by using two separate criteria's and concatenation.

```
  =AVERAGEIFS('FR motor'!$O$4:$O$68788,'FR motor'!$N$4:$N$68788,"<"&$C10+5,'FR motor'!$N$4:$N$68788,">"&$C10-5,'FR motor'!$E$4:$E$68788,D$11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS('FR motor'!$O$4:$O$68788,'FR motor'!$N$4:$N$68788,$C5:$C15,'FR motor'!$E$4:$E$68788,D$11))/SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS('FR motor'!$N$4:$N$68788,$C5:$C15,'FR motor'!$E$4:$E$68788,D$11))
```

To understand this, you can check [my example file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1VVp2dVRFYzhmWkE).

Comment: I supposed that you meant the criteria should be range like `C5:C15`